# How to create installer from Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am trying to install my program to specific folder in Program Files. How do I do this from VS 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Express Editions do not include Windows Installer technology read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kt85ked.aspx)

Comment: check this [create setup project](http://vijirajkumar.blogspot.com/2010/03/create-setup-and-deployment-project.html)

Comment: If you have the Pro Edition follow this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ddxk2ye.aspx